# CSS pseudo elements translate faster than main element

Tags: css, css-animations, pseudo-element

I have a simple div with a before and after pseudo element. I use keyframes to transform everything along the y axis.

The pseudo elements move faster than the main element and I have no idea why.

I explicitly set the position and inset on my pseudo elements and inherited the animation.

Here is my entire source code example:

```css
      body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: black;
      }
      .snow {
        position: absolute;
        content: "";
        inset: 0;
        background-image: radial-gradient(4px 4px at 100px 50px, #fff, transparent);
        animation: snowAnimation 4s linear infinite;
      }

      .snow::after,
      .snow::before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        inset: 0;
        background-image: radial-gradient(4px 4px at 100px 50px, #fff, transparent);
        animation: inherit;
      }

      @keyframes snowAnimation {
        from {
          transform: translateY(0);
        }
        to {
          transform: translateY(650px);
        }
      }
```

```html
  <body>
    <div class="snow"></div>
  </body>
```

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)
Instead of a link to an external website, or pasting code on it's own, [provide a code snippet to reproduce the issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do/358993#358993) here.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudo elements are children of their main elements. If you translate the main element, the pseudo elements are along for the ride. Applying the same translation to an element and its pseudo-element is sort of like throwing a 60mph pitch out of a car already traveling 60mph—you'll end up with a ball traveling 120mph.

Answer (score 1):

The pseudo elements run visibly faster, because you are simultaneously animating their parent, too! since the parent also goes down, you make the way for the pseudo element longer, but it has the same duration for the animation. Thus it has more way to go in the same amount of time. Thats why it looks faster.

Make the animation for the pseudo elements slower, or have two elements `<div>`'s next to each other without an animated parent.